# What is the right spelling for this agar?

Tags: homework, microbiology

I could not spell the agar [gonoline-uroline] which I heard yesterday.
My spelling is so wrong that I could not find it in Google.

**What is the right spelling for this agar?**

Comment: Might help if you tell us what it is used for.

Comment: It's completely illogical to change the question after a comment and an answer to the original question.

Comment: @AlanBoyd I agree, now it looks I did not answer question at all. The authors suggested to open a new questions if the original one has solved and generated other questions.

Comment: I rolled back and opened a new a question: http://biology.stackexchange.com/questions/15261/what-is-the-benefit-of-using-gonoline-euroline-in-combination

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The first word is ok, there is agar called Gonoline, the second one is probably Euroline and there is an agar with this word too (Liver IgG Euroline).

I've found both of them on the [Italian site](http://www.marigoitalia.com/public/reagenti.txt), probably the are not one, but two agars.

Comment: Now, I am thinking why they are using these two agars in combination. The topic was Pathogenous cocci.

Comment: I actually don't think this is right (not that it's your fault given the question), but I'm pretty sure Euroline is brand name for a synthetically printed ELISA like assay.  I really don't think there's any agar involved.

Answer (score 0):

Looking at your two questions together, I think you mean gonoline media, followed by blood agar.  To be honest, I feel like this question would be off topic.  You may be referring to a specific blood agar, like Chocolate agar, but that would be wild speculation.

Gonoline media is often used for Neisseriaceae, so perhaps you are specifically looking at Gonorrhea?