# What is the benefit of using Gonoline-Euroline in combination?

Tags: microbiology

I was heard that this combination first Gonoline and other culture another culture on Euroline is good one.

**What is the benefit of using Gonoline-Euroline in combination?**

Comment: What's the context, I've never heard of using them in combination/not sure you really mean to be asking about Euroline.

Comment: Please, close. This is too unclear to be discussed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looking at your other question, I think there's some serious editing that needs to be done to clarify this question.

Still I think there is a quick and easy answer to your question.  Gonoline media makes an excellent transfer media.  If you are out in the field some where and want to take a swab for further analysis, you could easily choose a gonoline media for transport.  Then you would want to follow that up with some selective blood agars that might show a pathogenic species that you were looking for.  Thus to use gonoline media with any other medium, is merely to preserve your sample for plating on your diagnostic media/agar later.

Again, looking at your related question, I could only guess that you meant chocolate agar, because you might be hunting Neisseriaceae (which you should put in the question if you are).

Comment: I'm also ok with closure